# vscode extension [tht13.python]: 'configuration.jsonValidation.url'

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I got this error notification while using VSCode:

```
[tht13.python]: 'configuration.jsonValidation.url' must be
                an absolute URL or start with './' to reference 
                schemas located in the extension.
```

I have found and changed `jsonValidation` to:

```
"jsonValidation": [
    {
        "fileMatch": ".condarc",
        "url": "./schemas/condarc.json"
    },
    {
        "fileMatch": "environment.yml",
        "url": "./schemas/conda-environment.json"
    },
    {
        "fileMatch": "meta.yaml",
        "url": "./schemas/conda-meta.json"
    }
]
```

in `package.json`, but it still doesn't work.

How to figure out this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using the extension "Python for VSCode" (tht13.python). It looks like this extension is not maintained anymore ([last commit on Jun 13, 2018](https://github.com/tht13/Python-vscode/commits/master))

Maybe you should switch to another extension. I'm quite happy with the "Python" (ms-python.python) extension from Microsoft https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

Comment: Unfortunately the ms-python.python is not compatible with the annotation syntax of Python3 :(

Comment: @nowox Can you be more specific what you mean by "not compatible with the annotation syntax of Python3"?
Type hints and docstrings are working fine for me.

Comment: My bad, I add an issue with a remaining ghost of this obsolete extension.